# How to insert multiple attributes using update_by_query in Elastic Search using perl wrapper Search::Elasticsearch

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I want to insert multiple attributes based on some condition in the Elastic search index using Perl module: Search::Elasticsearch.  I am able to insert one attribute using the following command:

```
$results = $e->update_by_query(
     index => 'fileindex_db',
     body  => {
         query => {
             match => {
                 "file.filename" => $val->{document_name}
             }
         },
     script => {
         source => "ctx._source.meta.put(\"UserName\",\"$val->{User_name}\")",
         lang => "painless"
     },
});
```

In the above command, 'fileindex_db' is the name of the index in Elastic search.  It matches the filename with the given document name: '$val->{document_name}' and then inserts a new attribute "Username: Value" in the index.  I can insert one value, 'Username', using the above command.  If I need to add more attributes, like Address, Phone, Email address etc., what should I adapt in the above command to be able to add multiple attributes together?

Comment: How is the `put` function defined?